# Good and safe form validation

Tags: php, forms

What would be the best and most secure way to validate a form with PHP? On for example: length, email, emptyness, specialchars, etc.

Is it safe to use filter_var for this? Or should I define them all in a function one by one manually. Or are there other ways.

Sorry I just want to make sure since I run against this question a lot of times when I build a form.

Answer (score 1):

Validation should be done on both the client side and the server side. The client side validation makes your server side script encounter less (or possibly none) errors. This is desirable because typically you don't like getting too many errors on the server side.

That being said, there are many ways how you can validate your inputs with PHP. It depends on the context. For example, checking emptiness (like you said yourself), or whether some input is numeric or not, checking the length of the value given (for example minimum length may be applicable), or whether an email address is really an email address! filter_var() may not always be sufficient.

Comment: To follow up: there are definitely right and wrong ways to do client/server validation. Duplicating all of your PHP validation code in JavaScript is a _wrong_ way to do it. I have been involved in numerous projects where the client side validation wasn't in sync with the server side. To be honest, the best solution I have seen _to date_ (doesn't mean that better solutions aren't out there) was a dummy controller on a server that took _any_ arbitrary form data and validated it against a set of rules via AJAX. It was an extremely quick call (<10ms) and best of all, accurate.

Comment: Could you share the controller here? It's worth checking whether it would work for my project too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions on the server side. But I'd consider using javascript to validate the form fields on the client side. You don't want to get information back an forth from the server just to check if the fields are ok, it will consume useless server time.

Comment: If I would validate them with javascript should I still use regular expressions on the server side? Or is this not necessary. Because like Ergin Keles said client side can be changed by the visitor.

Comment: Lets say the visitors who hack your site are counted very few, but naturally it's better to have both sides validation to account for these misfortunes. Also, check W3 on form validation ( http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp ) and this regular expressions for JS form validation ( http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html ) and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best validation process is to validate the data with regular expressions. You can define how many characters are necessary (at least or at most), which characters are allowed or not allowed and even you can define the exact format of the data.

Validation must be done in both sides. Server side and client side. You do the validation in client side and ease the job of server side. Even you do the validation client side, malicious-minded people can hack your code. There must be a validation in the server side too.

filter_var function is useful too. I use it to validate email addresses.